# Android/Glass: How to trigger surfaceDestroyed

Tags: android, multithreading, surfaceview, google-glass, surfaceholder

Hey everyone I am fairly new to the android/glass development so please correct me if I am wrong.

I tried to create a High Frequency Live Card which is fine. However when I close the app, the function surfaceDestroyed() did not get trigger and thread.quit() did not get called.

I tried looking into the sample project stopwatch/timer and apparently they did not stop the thread as well. According to the documentation, surfaceDestroyed gets called right before the surface is destroy but what is my surface? I also read something call surfaceview, are they the same thing? is surfaceview my customview or livecard?

https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/ui/live-cards#creating_high-frequency_live_cards

Appreciate any kind of help!!!﻿

```
/ ***
  * LiveCardRender Class
*** /
public class LiveCardRender implements DirectRenderingCallback {
    private static final long FRAME_TIME_MILLIS = 33;
    private CustomView mCustomView;
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private boolean mPaused;
    private RenderThread mRenderThread;

    private class RenderThread extends Thread {
        private boolean mShouldRun;

        public RenderThread() {
            mShouldRun = true;
        }

        private synchronized boolean shouldRun() {
            return mShouldRun;
        }

        public synchronized void quit() {
            mShouldRun = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (shouldRun()) {
                draw(mCustomView);
                SystemClock.sleep(FRAME_TIME_MILLIS);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        mHolder = holder;
        updateRendering();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        mHolder = null;
        updateRendering();
    }

    @Override
    public void renderingPaused(SurfaceHolder holder, boolean paused) {
        mPaused = paused;
        updateRendering();
    }

    private synchronized void updateRendering() {

        boolean shouldRender = (mHolder != null) && !mPaused;
        boolean rendering = mRenderThread != null;

        if (shouldRender != rendering) {
            if (shouldRender) {
                mRenderThread = new RenderThread();
                mRenderThread.start();
            } else {
                mRenderThread.quit();
                mRenderThread = null;
            }
        }
    }

    private void draw(View view) {

        Canvas canvas;
        try {
            canvas = mHolder.lockCanvas();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return;
        }
        if (canvas != null) {
            view.draw(canvas);
            mHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    }
}

/ ***
  * LaunchService Class that uses LiveCardRender to update the live card
*** /
public class LaunchService extends Service {
    private static final String LIVE_CARD_TAG = "motion_card";
    private TimelineManager mTimelineManager;
    private LiveCard mLiveCard;
    private LiveCardRender mLiveCardRender;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        mTimelineManager = TimelineManager.from(this);
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (mLiveCard == null) {
            mLiveCard = mTimelineManager.createLiveCard(LIVE_CARD_TAG);
            mLiveCardRender = new LiveCardRender(this);
            mLiveCard.setDirectRenderingEnabled(true);
            mLiveCard.getSurfaceHolder().addCallback(mLiveCardRender);
            mLiveCard.publish(PublishMode.REVEAL);
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        if (mLiveCard != null && mLiveCard.isPublished()) {
            if (mLiveCardRender != null) {
                mLiveCard.getSurfaceHolder().removeCallback(mLiveCardRender);
            }
            mLiveCard.unpublish();
            mLiveCard = null;
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you close your app? The samples' rendering thread do get killed when the LiveCard gets unpublished: this only happens when the Service is stopped.

Comment: Mine doesnt. For example the google stopwatch sample, I putted a Log message in the draw(View view) function and even after I close the app with the menu option "stop". The Log message keep on going in LogCat. And the Log message inside surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) was never get called

Comment: Hum, this seems like a bug... Another way you could stop your rendering thread would be to manually call `onSurfaceDestroyed` when your Service's `onDestroyed` method is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the bug is here, inside `onDestroy`:

```
if (mLiveCard != null && mLiveCard.isPublished()) {
    if (mLiveCardRender != null) {
        mLiveCard.getSurfaceHolder().removeCallback(mLiveCardRender);
    }
    mLiveCard.unpublish();
```

By removing the callback before the `unpublish` method is called, the system no longer knows whose `surfaceDestroyed` method to call when the card is removed afterwards. You can actually remove call to `removeCallback` entirely; it's unnecessary.

It looks like this is a bug in some of our samples that we missed as our APIs evolved. Thanks for catching it and we'll have them updated shortly!

Comment: Awesome! Go Glass Team Go!